# Parse Server S3 file adapter with Heroku app

Tags: heroku, amazon-s3, parse-server

I am trying to set up the s3 file adapter but I'm not sure if i am getting the formatting of something incorrect or something.  I have followed this:

https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/wiki/Configuring-File-Adapters#configuring-s3adapter

Guide exactly but when i uncomment the block of code below and put in my aws credentials then push the setup back to Heroku the app or dashboard won't start any longer, saying there is an application error:

```
//**** File Storage ****//
 filesAdapter: new S3Adapter(
    {
    "xxxxxxxx",
    "xxxxxxxx",
    "xxxxxxxx",
    {directAccess: true}
    }
 )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would set it up as follows for Heroku:

Make sure that after performing all steps described in the guide your policy looks similar to this:

```
 {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET_NAME",
                "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET_NAME/*"
            ]
        }
     ]
 }
```

Now apply this policy to the bucket: select your bucket in S3 console, tap ‘Properties’ button in the top right corner. Expand ‘Permissions’ section, press ‘Edit bucket policy’ and paste json above in the text field.

[image]

Configure Parse Server in the `index.js` file:

```
var S3Adapter = require('parse-server').S3Adapter;
var s3Adapter = new S3Adapter(
    "AWS_KEY",
    "AWS_SECRET_KEY",
    "bucket-name",
    { directAccess: true }
);
```

and add two lines to the Parse Server init  (`var api = new ParseServer({..})`):

```
filesAdapter: s3Adapter,
fileKey: process.env.PARSE_FILE_KEY
```

Comment: Thanks for posting mate.  Id followed all the setup guides but used process.env. for the environment variables.  I used something i found on GitHub and removed the curly brackets from the directAccess var and it seems to be working (at the moment)

Comment: Have you seen any guides for setting up mailgun? https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server-simple-mailgun-adapter is a bare bones

Answer (score 2):

Similar to Cliff's post, .S3Adapter has to be outside the ()

```
var S3Adapter = require('parse-server').S3Adapter;
```

And then inside parse server init:

```
 filesAdapter: new S3Adapter(
    {
    accessKey: process.env.S3_ACCESS_KEY || '',
    secretKey: process.env.S3_SECRET_KEY || '',
    bucket: process.env.S3_BUCKET || '',
    directAccess: true
    }
 )
```

This worked in this case.